# Как удалить букву из списка?

Tags: python, список

```
a="Don't panic!"
a=list(a)
for x in a:
    if x not in "on tap":
        a.remove(x)
print(a)
```

Объясните пожалуйста почему не удаляется буква "c" из списка. Ведь её нет в строке "on tap"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому, что вы меняете прямо список, которым вы проходите. Вы постепенно получаете такие списки:

```
['D', 'o', 'n', "'", 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'c', '!']
['o', 'n', "'", 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'c', '!']
['o', 'n', 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'c', '!']
['o', 'n', 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'c', '!']
['o', 'n', 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'c']
```

что лучше видимо в строковой форме

```
Don't panic!
on't panic!
ont panic!
ont panc!
```

Нужно проходит по **копии** списка, которую очень просто получите, когда добавите к нему [:]

```
a = "Don't panic!"
a = list(a)
for x in a[:]:            # <----- Здесь разница!
    if x not in "on tap":
        a.remove(x)
print(a)
print("".join(a))         # Может быть, что вы хотели вывести строку
```

Вывод:

> ```
> ['o', 'n', 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'n']
> ont pan
> ```

Comment: Или `a.copy()`.

Comment: @Victor, когда вы думаете, что так короче...

Comment: ??????????????????????

Answer (score 3):

Потому что Ваш код изменяет (уменьшает) список во время итерирования по нему.

Добавьте вывод `x` в цикле, и Вы увидите что происходит.

```
a="Don't panic!"
a=list(a)
for x in a:
    print(x) # !!!
    if x not in "on tap":
        a.remove(x)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте генераторы вместо for:

```
new_a = [x for x in a if x in "on tap"]
print(new_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее подходящей для вашей задачи является стандартная функция `filter()` ([см. здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)):

```
a = "Don't panic!"
a = "".join(filter(lambda c : c not in "on tap", a))
print(a)
```

Первый аргумент — функция, которая применяется к каждому элементу, и в итоговый генератор попадают только отфильтрованные по ней. `.join()` нужен для соединения элементов в одну строку